# Why am I getting a 'NameError: name 'functions' is not defined' when running dir(functions) in Python console?

Tags: nameerror

*I've created a module in a file called functions.py and imported it in Coding Exercise 15.py .
*

*Code in functions.py :
*
FILEPATH = "../bonus/files/todos.txt"

def get_todos(filepath = FILEPATH): # (parameter)
with open(filepath, "r") as file_local:
todos_local = file_local.readlines()
return todos_local

def write_todos(todos_arg, filepath= FILEPATH): # (parameter)
""""Write the to-do items list in the text file."""
with open(filepath,'w') as file:
file.writelines(todos_arg)

*Code in Coding Exercise 15.py :*

import functions # local module created
import time # standard module written by python code developers

now = time.strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
print("It is",now)
while True:
user_action = input("Type add/new or show, edit, complete or exit: ")
user_action = user_action.strip()

```
if user_action.startswith("add"):
    todo = user_action[4: ]

    todos = functions.get_todos() # functions is a module (imported script)
    todos.append(todo + '\n')

    functions.write_todos(todos)

elif user_action.startswith("show"):

    todos = functions.get_todos()

    for index, item in enumerate(todos):
        item = item.strip("\n")
        row = f"{index + 1}-{item}"
        print(row)
        # enumerate : establish the number of / mention (a number of things) one by one


elif user_action.startswith("edit"):
    try:
        number = int(user_action[5:]) # "Slicing"
        print(number)
        number = number - 1

        todos = functions.get_todos()

        new_todo = input("Enter a todo: ")
        todos[number] = new_todo + '\n'

        functions.write_todos(todos)

    except ValueError:
        print("Your command is not valid.")
        continue
    # runs another cycle of the while loop


elif user_action.startswith("complete"):
    try:
        number = int(user_action[8:])

        todos = functions.get_todos()

        index = number - 1
        todo_to_remove = todos[index].strip('\n')
        todos.pop(index)

        functions.write_todos(todos)

        message = f"Todo {todo_to_remove} was removed from the list"
        print(message)
    except IndexError:
        print("There is no item with that number. ")
        continue

elif user_action.startswith("exit"):
    print("Hey, you've entered an unknown command")
    break
```

else:
print('This command is not valid')

print("Bye!")

I'm running the dir(functions) in the python console but the following error pops up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
coro = func()
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'functions' is not defined